# What does the int returned by ResponseWriter.Write mean?

Tags: http, go

https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L139

I would've expected the signature to be `Write([]byte) error`, not `Write([]byte) (int, error)`. I also can't find any good explanation from looking through usages, and the documentation comment doesn't explain the return values.

What does the returned `int` mean?

Comment: Number of bytes written.

Comment: `ResponseWriter.Write()` is to implement [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer). You can read more about it there.

Comment: Thanks. Does either of you feel like turning your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ResponseWriter.Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) method is to implement the general [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) interface, so a value of `http.ResponseWriter` can be used / passed to any utility function that accepts / works on an `io.Writer`.

`io.Writer` has exactly one `Write()` method and it details exactly the "contract" of `Write`, what it should return and how it should work:

```
type Writer interface {
    Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

> Write writes len(p) bytes from p to the underlying data stream. **It returns the number of bytes written from p (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered that caused the write to stop early.** Write must return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p).

Comment: So the reason it's not documented is that `Writer` is one of the super common interfaces that most go devs know by heart.